# C# calling a decimal method with arguments in a form

Tags: c#, methods, decimal

So I am trying to do this for a hw and in my class I have this double method for converting from cm to inch:

```
public decimal Conversion(decimal Input)
{
    return Input * (decimal)0.393701;
}
```

The problem is when I try to call it in a form, and I need to send arguments to it.

```
public partial class frmCmVoInch : Form
{
    public frmCmVoInch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public frmCmVoInch(mainForm parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MdiParent = parent;
    }

    private void btnKonverzija_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal parsed;
        decimal.TryParse(txtVlez.Text, out parsed);
        CmVoInch cmVoInch = new CmVoInch(decimal.Parse(txtVlez.Text));
        rtbIzlez = txtVlez.Text + " cm = " + cmVoInch.Konverzija(parsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what does the error state?

Comment: What is the error message? Why does your class take a decimal as constructor argument?

Comment: You're calling an instance method without an instance. `Conversion` should probably be a static method given it has no dependencies. Does `CmVoInch` actually have a constructor that takes a decimal? That wouldn't seem to be useful. And you're trying to return a value from a void method.

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error you received. I don't know if this is a culture issue, e.g. if parsing the text to decimal with `decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` would work. Post the exception so we can try to fix the exception.

Comment: Seems like your `Conversion` method should `static` if you want to call it that way.  Also you cannot return a `string` from a `void` method.  Did you mean to concatenate to `txtInp` or maybe assign the new value to it instead?

Comment: "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property" - Thats the error I am getting. It takes decimal arguments cause it's stated in the homework for the method to have decimal arguments. The return of value in void method was error in typing, I fixed it, still don't work

Comment: And the conversion method is implemented from an Interface

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski if you're going to update your post please append a title stating "EDIT" and below that append your new edits, **don't** edit the original post as your problems are getting solved.

Comment: I'd agree with @OusmaneMahyDiaw. None of the answers make any sense any more given the question is now nothing like where you started.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Sorry guys, I am new here, so still learning the rules of stack overflow. Should I change back my post to the original and then put the updates under it? Or leave it like this and be careful next time?

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski just leave it as it is now and I'd recommend reading the [**SO documentation tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation). welcome to SO ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a typo:

```
rtbOutp = txtInp.Text + " cm = " + CmVoInch.Conversion(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
```

Should be:

```
rtbOutp = txtInp.Text + " cm = " + cmVoInch.Conversion(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
```

Note the change in case of `CmVoInch`. The first is the type name, so attempts to call an instance method without an instance, hence the error *an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property*. The second correctly refers to the instance of that class you created on the previous line.

You also need to change to set the *text* property of the `RichTextBox`, as you can't assign a string to it:

```
rtbOutp.Text = txtInp.Text + " cm = " + cmVoInch.Conversion(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that. I am still new to C# lol. But now it says I cannot do implicit conversion from type "String" to 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'

Comment: Evidently `rtbOutp` is a `RichTextBox`, so you can't assign a string to it. See my update.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I am new to stack overflow too, so how do I rate your answer as the right one and close the question? :)

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski You might want to read [this help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski you cannot close the question once there are answers. Also, read my comment on your post.

Answer (score 0):

> but it is String, and it wont accept it even if I convert it to
>   decimal. Any way I can fix this?

the issue is **not** with the `Conversion` method.

the issue is the `btnKonverzija_Click`  method returns `void` and you're trying to return a `string` value. you **cannot** do that.

```
private void btnKonverzija_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CmVoInch cmVoInch = new CmVoInch(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
        return txtInp.Text + " cm = " + CmVoInch.Conversion(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
}
```

**note** - `C#` is a case-sensitive language, currently, you're calling the `Converion` method as if it belongs to a class rather you should use `cmVoInch.Conversion` not `CmVoInch.Conversion`.

full solution:

```
private void btnKonverzija_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CmVoInch cmVoInch = new CmVoInch(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
        rtbIzlez.Text = txtInp.Text + " cm = " + cmVoInch.Conversion(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));
}
```

Comment: Haha I can't believe I made that mistake lol. I had it like that with a global variable too, and it didn't work. Let me edit the code

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski sure ;)

Comment: I have edited the code, mind if you check it again? Thanks :D

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski sure i can :) but you'll have to state what error are you getting now or what exactly is not working?

Comment: This issue **is** with the `Conversion` method. You can't call an instance method without an instance.

Comment: "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property"  - Thats the error I am getting. And it is inherited from Interface, so it shouldn't be static, should it?

Comment: @CharlesMager here's the instance of the class CmVoInch:    CmVoInch cmVoInch = new CmVoInch(decimal.Parse(txtInp.Text));

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski It's case sensitive. You're using the class name, not the name of the instance.

Comment: @CharlesMager OP made a mistake with spelling. However, OP did create an instance which the method operates on so the issue **is not** with the conversion method.

Comment: @HristijanBoshkovski yes, but that error is the cause of the stated *an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property* error. So the typo is rather important here.